# TFLearn - Metrics for validate and evaluate?

Tags: validation, tflearn

I'm using [AlexNet](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/images/alexnet.py) model in TFLearn and there is a method to define the regression layer, which is:

```
tflearn.layers.estimator.regression (incoming, placeholder='default', optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metric='default', learning_rate=0.001, dtype=tf.float32, batch_size=64, shuffle_batches=True, to_one_hot=False, n_classes=None, trainable_vars=None, restore=True, op_name=None, validation_monitors=None, validation_batch_size=None, name=None)
```

and it states that `"A metric can also be provided, to evaluate the model performance."`. So I'm wondering when is this metric also used for validation or only used evaluation? If it's not used in validation then based on what metric does the validation work?

EDIT 1: I found out that the metric declared in regression() method is actually used for validating as well. The default metric is `Accuracy`. However one thing I don’t understand is that when I don't use `validation_set` (or set it to **None**), the summary while training still outputs the `acc` value. So how is this accuracy value computed?

EDIT 2: Found the answer here: https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/issues/357

Answer (score 0):

The training accuracy `acc` is based on your training data, while the validation accuracy `val_acc` is based on the validation data. So omitting validation data won't change the output.